# Having trouble converting a numerical console application to a MVC3 web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm new to MVC having previously done a lot of numerical programming in C# console applications. I'd like to eventually build web applications that run these same type of programs. My first attempt though has run into difficulties.

This is a very basic application that will take in a number from a form and then calculate the sum of all the numbers between 1 and that number that are divisible by either 3 or 5. I created a simple Model class which contains a variable that will correspond to the input:

```
namespace MvcDemo.Models
{
public  class Values 
{


    public int Number { get; set; }

}
}
```

I then created a controller class:

```
namespace MvcDemo.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    Values v = new Values();


    public ActionResult Index()
    { return View(); }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(int number)
    {

        v.Number = number;

        return View(v); 
    }

}
}
```

and finally the View:

```
@Model MvcDemo.Models.Values

@{ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";}

<h1>Sum of Multiples of 3 & 5</h1>


@using (Html.BeginForm()){

@Html.TextBox("number");

    <input type="submit" />   
}

@{
int n;
List<int> nums = new List<int>();
int sum = 0;

if(@Model.Number!=null)
{
n = @Model.Number;
}
else
{
    n = 10;    
}

for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
    {
        nums.Add(i);
    }
}

for (int j = 0; j < nums.Count; j++)
{
    sum += nums[j];
}


}
<p>The sum of the factors is: @sum</p>
```

When I try and run this I get an exception saying "Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference". This is referring to my view page where I'm trying to assign n. I'm not quite sure how to get around this.

Also is it bad practice to have the numerical logic within the view class or would this be better within the controller class?

Comment: You should put all of your logic in the controller.

Comment: Should it be placed on a method on its own or within the relevant action method for that view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting an error because the model is null.

If you use a strongly-typed view, you wouldn't get that error, but since you wrote `@Model` rather than `@model`, your view is not strongly typed.

Comment: I changed to @model and now I'm getting an exception saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." whilst pointing at the line if(@Model.Number!=null) in the view

Comment: @Sperick: That's because you didn't pass a model in the action.  `Model` is null.

Comment: I thought I did with the line "return View(v)" but I've just seen that that was in the Post method only-thanks!